# C# Winforms How to Understand Form object is moved

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to trigger an event only when the form is moved via the mouse click over the title bar. I could not find proper event for this.

Currently I implemented a move event for my forms in winform. I only want the move event to be triggered when the user drags the form via clicking on the title bar. However, this event is triggered also when form is tried to be resized by mouse or minimized/maximized. How can I disable this? I only want to trigger an event only when the form is moved. I am trying to implement my own floating forms and I want to catch this specific event to change the MDiParent of the form.

Comment: Not sure if there is such an event. If not - you can keep the last form size in a data member. Then when the event triggers check if there was a change in size (and update last size).

Comment: Also, I tried to do it with MouseMove and MouseDown events, but the forms does not trigger these event. I did not understand why

Comment: @BilalCan Because this events are for `Form`'s client area.

Comment: @jtxkopt thanks for the information. I was struggling with them. Do you know how can I do this move event in an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the form is resized and the `Form`'s `FormWindowState` is changed in the `Move` event, if not so, you can decide that `Form` is moving using the title bar.

To do so, you should cache both the window state and size each time when `Move` event is triggered.

**Note**: The `Move` event is triggered even when you change the location of the form via the `Location` property, not only using the title bar. So, the event `FromDragged` will be triggered in the case. This is a *"false positive"*.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WhenDraggingUsingCaptionBar
{
    public partial class CustomForm : Form
    {
        public CustomForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormDragged += Form1_FormDragged;
        }

        private void Form1_FormDragged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }

        public event EventHandler FormDragged;
        private Size _cachedSize = new Size(0, 0);
        private FormWindowState _cachedState = FormWindowState.Normal; 
        private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cachedSize == Size && _cachedState == WindowState)
                if (FormDragged != null)
                    FormDragged(this, new EventArgs());

            _cachedSize = Size;
            _cachedState = WindowState;
        }
    }
}
```

As an addition, there is a low-level solution using `Win32` API. This solution eliminates the *"false-positive"* issues in the approach above.

You can handle the `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message. This message is sent when you down the mouse left button in the non-client area of the window. When we get the message, we set a variable to `true`. We also catch another message `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` to understand when the dragging the window is stopped and set the variable to `false`.

If the variable is set to `true` when the move event is triggered, we can say the window is being dragged using the title bar.

```
public class CustomForm : Form
{
    public CustomForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        FormDragged += Form1_FormDragged;
        FormDragging += Form1_FormDragging;
    } 
    private void Form1_FormDragged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FormDragged: Time = {0}", DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void Form1_FormDragging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("FormDragging: Time = {0}", DateTime.Now);
    }

    public event EventHandler FormDragged; 
    public event EventHandler FormDragging; 
    private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1; 
    private const int WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232; 
         
    private bool _ncbuttonDown = false;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN)
            _ncbuttonDown = true;
        else if (m.Msg == WM_EXITSIZEMOVE)
        { 
            _ncbuttonDown = false;
            OnFormDragged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMove(e);
        if (_ncbuttonDown == true)
            OnFormDragging(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    protected virtual void OnFormDragging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormDragging != null)
            FormDragging(sender, e);
    }
    protected virtual void OnFormDragged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormDragged != null)
            FormDragged(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look the updated second method. I deleted the previous one.

Comment: Can we also simulate the move event after changing the parent of the form. In FormDragged event I change the MDiParent as null in order to make it float. But with this I am loosing the control of mouse. The user needs to reclick to the title bar to drag the window to locate whereever he/she wants.

Comment: The problem you are facing now is another topic and should be asked on another post.